# Attaching a DLL to a Game

Tags: c++, hook, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I would like to attach my DLL to a game to add more features.

The DLL is 95% done, the problem is in finding the best and easy way to load this DLL from within the game.

My idea is to use this technique:

> dinput_ori.dll (old dll)
> dinput.dll (my dll that points to dinput_ori.dll)

I don't need to access any members of original DLL, but only load my new DLL.

I am searching for a generic DLL source code that can do the following:

```
bool WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{

    std::string DLLFileOri = "dinput_ori.dll";

    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Load dll

        LoadOriDll(DLLFileOri);

        MsgBox("This DLL was loaded.");

        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

        // Close the DLL
        
        UnloadOriDll(DLLFileOri);

        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In this case the name of my DLL is "dinput.dll".

Is there a generic source code that can do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ hooking a dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137148/c-hooking-a-dll)

Comment: Is bit different, I have already the code to hook, but I need a easy example about how rediect my dll to original dll.

Comment: Did you read raptorfactor's answer about adding the old DLL to your own DLL's import table? That loads the old DLL together with yours for free.

Comment: Yes, If I have understand he suggest to use IAT/EAT and not detours. I'am not an expert but IAT/EAT simple replace a function with another function inside a different DLL if I have understand. I need only  the code (or a tool) that attach my dll to the exe. Inside my DLL there is already ms detours that do what I need. In short I need a similar thing like cheat engine "Inject DLL" not others.